# Query for adding same column entries W.R.T its Foreign Key

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following table, with the attributes:

```
vendor_invoicedetails
   Venid(Pk)
   ven_inv_ref(Fk)
   Item_Code
   Item_Name
   UnitPrice
   VenQuantity
```

1. I want to multiply the `unitPrice` with `VenQuantity` to have a total price which I did with following query

   ```
   select item_code, 
          VEN_INV_REF, 
          unitprice * ven_itemquantity as total
     from vendor_invoicedetails;
   ```
2. The thing I want is to sum the the `TotalPrice` as Total of two same `Ven_inv_Ref(Fk)` column.

[image]

In the above picture I want sum those entries having same `VEN_INV_REF` number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @datatable TABLE
   (
     ITEM_CODE NVARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     ven_inv_ref NVARCHAR(50),
     Item_Name NVARCHAR(50),
     UnitPrice FLOAT, 
     VenQuantity INT
   )

INSERT INTO @datatable
(ITEM_CODE, ven_inv_ref, UnitPrice, VenQuantity)
VALUES ('battery', 15, 100, 4)

INSERT INTO @datatable
(ITEM_CODE, ven_inv_ref, UnitPrice, VenQuantity)
VALUES ('ABCDE', 16, 200, 4)

INSERT INTO @datatable
(ITEM_CODE, ven_inv_ref, UnitPrice, VenQuantity)
VALUES ('A4', 16, 400, 4)

-- whats in the table   
SELECT * 
FROM @datatable

-- group by reference
SELECT 
    ven_inv_ref, 
    SUM(UnitPrice*VenQuantity) AS totalvalue 
FROM @datatable
GROUP BY ven_inv_ref
```

Result

[image]